# override protocol extension default implementation

Tags: ios, swift, overriding, protocols

Consider following code

```
// GENERATED PROTOCOL, CANNOT BE MODIFIED
protocol SomeProtocol {
}

// GENERATED CLASS, CANNOT BE MODIFIED
class A {
}

// GENERATED CLASS, CANNOT BE MODIFIED
class B: A, SomeProtocol {
}



// I CAN CHANGE ONLY FROM HERE BELOW

extension SomeProtocol {
    func someMethod() {
        print("protocol implementation")
    }
}

extension B {
    func someMethod() {
        print("class implementation")
    }
}


let some: SomeProtocol = B()
some.someMethod() //this prints "protocol implementation"
```

I want some.someMethod() to print "class implementation". I know there are ways to achieve this, one would be to add in SomeProtocol someMethod, but, unfortunately, I cannot change none of SomeProtocol, A or B, these are generated. I can only play with extensions. Is there a way to achieve this without touching the 3 mentioned before?

Comment: If you don't annotate the type you get the class implementation

Comment: in above code just change `protocol SomeProtocol {  func someMethod() }`

Comment: @vadian I cannot do that

Comment: @Pratik Prajapati I already mentioned in description this is not gonna work for me

Comment: You cannot do `let some = B()`? Why?

Comment: @vadian because this is just an example, extracted from a more complex use case, some: SomeProtocol is in the signature of a method and I get in "some" an object of type B, I cannot change the method signature, I put it like this to keep it simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare the variable as the protocol type, it will always take the default implementation of the protocol method, since the method is declared in an extension of the protocol.

Without adding the method to the protocol declaration itself (which you've stated to be not possible for you), the only way to access the specific implementation of your conforming type is to downcast `some` to `B` or store it as `B` in the first place.

```
let some: SomeProtocol = B()
some.someMethod() //this prints "protocol implementation"
(some as? B)?.someMethod() // this prints "class implementation"

let someB = B()
someB.someMethod() // this prints "class implementation"
```

Comment: @Pasztor thanks!, this is clear, then with the code I have there is no way of achieving that

Comment: @Claudiu, if concrete type is erased by using protocol as type of the variable, you can do nothing

Comment: @Claudiu sadly yes, it seems with your restrictions, you cannot achieve your goals